# Disabling NUL-termination of strings in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, null-terminated

Is it possible to globally disable NUL-terminated strings in GCC?

I am using my own string library, and I have absolutely no need for the final NUL characters as it already stores the proper length internally in a struct.

However, if I wanted to append 10 strings, this would mean that 10 bytes are unnecessarily allocated on the stack. With wide strings it is even worse: As for x86, there are 40 bytes wasted; and for x86_64, 80 bytes!

I defined a macro to add those stack-allocated strings to my struct:

```
#define AppendString(ppDest, pSource) \
  AppendSubString(ppDest, (*ppDest)->len + 1, pSource, 0, sizeof(pSource) - 1)
```

Using `sizeof(...) - 1` works quite well but I am wondering whether I could get rid of NUL termination in order to save a few bytes?

Comment: What should happen to empty strings? How do you propose to deal with them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 80 bytes is not going to be a problem for your program.  Especially on x86.

Comment: On Linux and I assume all other OSes `wchar_t` is the same length regardless of the architecture. Linux in particular uses 4 bytes on both x86 and x86_64.

Comment: Good luck with replacing the string functions in C with your own versions. And all of the functions to which you pass a nul-terminated string. And getting adequate performance.

Could you explain a bit more about your problem so that you don't get shouted at for trying to save a byte by allocating two at the beginning of the string please?

Comment: Indeed, this is clearly premature optimization. Even if many language interpreters define their own string types, in many cases they still include the 0 byte because it's negligible compared to even length field/malloc overhead.

Comment: Firstly, the "problem" you are decribing is only poosible when all the strings are *string literals*, i.e. they are all known at compile time. It is rather strange to deal with a problem whose input is known at compile time, especially when it comes to such optimizations.

Comment: Secondly, if you really care of getting rid of null terminators, just initialize your char arrays in letter-by-letter manner, as in `char s[5] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }`.

Comment: Why, in the name of Charles Babbage, are you concerned with saving space like that?  Unless you're working on some extremely strange problem that you haven't mentioned, you don't need to do this, and you're going to cause far more problems for yourself than you solve.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür - If you have a size field, you could set the size to zero for empty strings.

Comment: Remember that when you pass a string to a function, you **really pass a pointer** and `sizeof (ptr)` knows nothing about the initial string.

Comment: I expected comments like this when posting my question. :)
@MatthieuF:
As you can see AppendSubString() expects the length as its last parameter. This allows me to continue using the Glibc functions until I have replaced them with my own. Here is an example taken from my HTTP library:

bytesRcvd = recv(sock, buf, RCVBUFSIZE, 0);
/* ... */
AppendSubString(response, (*response)->len + 1, buf, 0, bytesRcvd);

Comment: I implemented only 10 functions and they cover all string operations I have needed so far. They are kept very general though. For example, there is a SubStringEquals() function and three macros (StringBegins, StringEnds, StringEquals) using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty awful, but you can explicitly specify the length of every character array constant:

```
char my_constant[6] = "foobar";
assert(sizeof my_constant == 6);

wchar_t wide_constant[6] = L"foobar";
assert(sizeof wide_constant == 6*sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: You could make it a macro: `#define NEW_STRING(var, val) char var[sizeof(val)-1] = val`

Comment: If your own string type is defined as a struct of `{length; pointer}` then you might as well use length=0 and pointer=NULL -- accessing pointer would be invalid anyway, because there are no characters to read.

Comment: @intgr:
With your code I am getting: "error: wide character array initialized from non-wide string"

@Sinan Ünür: Even empty strings are NUL-terminated. That means that *sizeof() - 1* results 0 as expected. In my case AppendSubString() would stop right away and does not add anything.

@Matt B.:
I am aware of it but actually it does not solve my problem. The AppendString() macro is used in my code like this everywhere: *AppendString(&string, "Hello World");* As you can see, I am not using any variables for this purpose.

Comment: @timn: Oops, I forgot that you need to prefix `L""` to wide-character literals. I updated my example.

Comment: @timn: In the case of the string literal (like you cite `AppendString(&string, "Hello World")`), the `"Hello World"` is **not** stored on the stack (at least for x86*).  It's stored in the read-only segment of the executable, and `AppendString` receives a pointer to that segment.  So in this case, you're not increasing your stack size, but rather executable size.  I certainly hope one byte won't break you in either case, but this isn't even the one you're worried about.

Comment: Matt B.: Ah, that's interesting. Now I can continue with the current approach without having any bad feelings concerning the memory usage. :)

Comment: Nope, you can't. At least it's not portable. gcc-4.7.0 says _error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]_.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin So you downvoted because I couldn't predict the future 2.5 years ago, that a future GCC version would deem this an error?

Comment: The example still works with the GCC **C compiler**. Yes, the C++ compiler complains.

Comment: Fair enough, I should have checked the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you're only dealing with strings declared in your program:

```
 ....
 char str1[10];
 char str2[12];
 ....
```

and not with text buffers you allocate with `malloc()` and friends otherwise `sizeof` is not going to help you.

Anyway, i would just think twice about removing the \0 at the end: you would lose the compatibility with C standard library functions.

Unless you are going to rewrite any single string function for your library (sprintf, for example), are you sure you want to do it?

Comment: I am not using heap allocated strings because that is exactly what my string library is for. Manually allocating memory is too dangerous as there is always the risk of buffer overflows.

As stated above rewriting the string functions was not really hard. Thanks to C99 I might use a simple hack in order to still keep compatibility to Glibc functions: char tmp[string->len + 1]; tmp[string->len + 1] = '\0'; printf("%s", tmp);

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons for doing this but, if I understand how buffer overrun exploits work, having the string on the stack is more dangerous than having them allocated on the heap.

About adding the '\0' at the end, I don't see how the content of string is copied into temp, and I think that you're using a gcc extension rather than C99.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the details, but when I do

```
char my_constant[5]
```

it is possible that it will reserve 8 bytes anyway, because some machines can't address the middle of a word.

It's nearly always best to leave this sort of thing to the compiler and let it handle the optmisation for you, unless there is a really really good reason to do so.

Comment: It's called "alignment" (also "internal fragmentation"). It's true that throwing away the NUL byte does not reduce most strings, but when it does, it reduces by the alignment size. So, on average, each string would still consume 1 byte less memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Indeed this is only in case you are really low in memory.** Otherwise I don't recommend to do so.

It seems most proper way to do thing you are talking about is:

- To prepare some minimal 'listing' file in a form of:

```
    string1_constant_name "str1"
    string2_constant_name "str2"
    ...
```

- To construct utility which processes your file and generates declarations such as

```
    const char string1_constant[4] = "str1";
```

Of course I'd not recommend to do this by hands, because otherwise you can get in trouble after any string change.

So now you have both non-terminated strings because of fixed auto-generated arrays and also you have sizeof() for every variable. This solution seems acceptable.

**Benefits** are easy localization, possibility to add some level of checks to make this solution risk lower and R/O data segment savings.

**Drawback** is need to include all of such string constants in every module (as include to keep sizeof() known). So this only makes sense if your linker merges such symbols (some don't).

Comment: Nice idea! Unfortunately it requires me to always pull the whole code through a "preprocessor" before compiling. If there is really no such option in GCC to turn off NUL termination, I will stick with my current approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using **any** of the Standard Library function that deal with strings you can forget about the NUL terminating byte.

**No `strlen()`, no `fgets()`, no `atoi()`, no `strtoul()`, no `fopen()`, no `printf()` with the `%s` conversion specifier ...**

Declare your "not quite C strings" with just the needed space;

```
struct NotQuiteCString { /* ... */ };

struct NotQuiteCString variable;
variable.data = malloc(5);
data[0] = 'H'; /* ... */ data[4] = 'o'; /* "hello" */
```

Comment: Basically this is more or less what I am currently doing.

It might be indeed better to keep NUL-termination generally turned on but perhaps there is something like a pragma allowing me to enable/disable the NUL terminating byte for a given code part, i.e. my string library functions?

Comment: Just don't use it. You use arrays of `int` everyday, lots of time a day ... and you never even once used a terminating `int`. Do the same with `char` arrays (when I do that I specifically "sign" my `char`s: `signed char` or `unsigned char`: to me, only plain `char` can be `C` strings).

Answer (score 0):

Aren't these similar to Pascal-style strings, or Hollerith Strings?  I think this is only useful if you actually want the String data to preserve NULLs, in which you're really pushing around arbitrary memory, not "strings" per se.

Comment: Yes, I am using them in a similar way like Hollerith strings. In my code it is defined as follows: typedef struct { unsigned int len; unsigned int maxLen; char buf[0]; }
There are other advantages as well. Wikipedia (taken from "String literal") says:
 * eliminates text searching (for the delimiter character) and therefore requires significantly less overhead
 * avoids the (100% programmer induced) problem of delimiter collision
 * enables the inclusion of metacharacters that might otherwise be mistaken as commands
 * can be used for quite effective data compression of plain text strings

Answer (score 0):

The question uses false assumptions - it assumes that storing the length (e.g. implicitly by passing it as a number to a function) incurs no overhead, but that's not true.

While one might save space by not storing the 0-byte (or wchar), the size must be stored somewhere, and the example hints that it is passed as a constant argument to a function somewhere, which almost certainly takes more space, in code. If the same string is used multiple times, the overhead is per use, not per-string.

Having a wrapper that uses strlen to determine the length of a string and isn't inlined will almost certainly save more space.